# Geckodriver does not unload after WebDriver quited

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, geckodriver

```
...
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "c:\\drv\\geckodriver.exe");
FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
firefoxOptions.setBinary(firefoxBinary);
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);
...
driver.quit();
```

Аfter webdriver finished the `geckodriver.exe` still loaded in system and visible in windows system processes.

How to finish `geckodriver` process after webdriver quited?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have a typo in your code. I think you mean `driver.quit();`.